# Do not close Observable after error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I know that this question can appear pretty simple, but the resources on the web about Observables and error handling aren't so great (or maybe I'm just bad at searching).

I have a http request that returns an *Observable* of *Response*, these Responses can contain either data or an error message. If it contains data I want to extract it and parse it, if it contains the error message I want to skip all the other operators (about the parsing) and execute the error function in the subscriber.

I can do all this things throwing an Error:

```
http.get(...).
...
.do(res=>{
  if(res.error) throw new Error(res.error.message);
  return res;
})
```

and it works, it skips all the operators and it execute the error function. The problem is that, after the error, the *Subscriber* stops and doesn't accept data anymore.

If I analyze the Subscriber after the error, I notice that the properties **closed** and **isStopped** are set to *true* both. I want to prevent this, I want to keep the Observable active also after the errors. How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: not advisable after subscription to have them active

Comment: It looks like you just need to use the `catch()` operator and return `Observable.empty()` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in previous answers, this is the standard behaviour, guaranteed by contract of `Rxjs` observables. If you want to escape the contracts, you can `materialize` your source, in the case of which, instead of dealing with messages streamed through your observable, you will deal with meta-messages (called notifications, of the three types you expect, `next`, `error`, `complete`). There is no contract on meta-messages, which put the burden on you to create your error, and complete messages by hand, or use `dematerialize` to return back to the normal behaviour.

Generally speaking, observables are great for dataflow, while control flow is generally arduous (jumping, looping, conditional branching, etc.).

See the `Notification` documentation here: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Notification.js~Notification.html.

See the `materialize` documentation here: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-materialize

So if you want to deal with errors without stopping your source observable, you can do something like that:

```
function process(source, success, error) {
  return source.materialize()
    .map(function(notification){
      const value = notification.value; // that is the actual message data
      if (notification.kind === 'N') {
        // that is a next message, we keep it a next message
        return Notification.createNext(success(value));
      }
      if (notification.kind === 'E') {
        // that is a error message, we turned into a next message
        return Notification.createNext(error(value));
      }
      if (notification.kind === 'C') {
        // that is a completed message, we keep it a completed message
        return Notification.createComplete();
      }
    })
   .dematerialize()
}
```

You can then use this function with your source observable and passing it the success and error function which process the streamed value. As you can see, the technique here is to turn an error message into a normal message, and then revert back to normal.

This is done from the back of my head so untested, so keep me updated if that was helpful to you. I used a similar technique many times with Rxjs v4, I believe it should translate to Rxjs v5 in a straight forward manner.

Comment: this won't work, as a stream will anyway complete as soon as one of the operators throws. Creating a disposable stream inside `flatMap`/`switchMap` would do the trick.

Comment: Do you have any code showing the recommended techinique failing? I have been doing this is Rxjs 4 back in the days several times without a hiccup. In any case, feel free to add your own answer for all to see. The `flatMap/switchMap` you recommend should also work indeed, I also used that several times.

Comment: fair enough. I'll check again with rxjs 4, it could be a change of behaviour between versions though I doubt it. Will check my old code to see if that is the case.

Comment: actually it does not really matter, the fact is the technique does not work with the newer versions, so I would kindly ask you write an answer for the question, and I will delete mine and upvote yours.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking is literally breaking the contract of the Observable. An Observable is defined as a producer of 0 or more values, and if the producer is finished producing values, it will call the `complete` handler on its observer, and if there's an error, it will call `error`.

But once it calls `complete` OR `error`, its contract is that it will never call `next` on its observer again.

There are ways around this - by composing your observables correctly, you can resume your stream with a new observable. But without additional context, it's hard to guide you further. The basic idea is around using the .catch operator in your observable chain to create a new observable on error, but again, additional context would be needed to provide an example.

**Edit:**

As @cartant helpfully added, [see the observable contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html)